# Pointer 'snap to' Start button when swiping from right on touchpad

Tags: windows-8, touchpad, gestures, charms-bar

I want my mouse pointer to 'snap' to the Start button when I swipe from right on the touchpad to unveil the Charms Bar. I've seen this in some ASUS Windows 8 laptops.

Because dragging my mouse pointer from one end of the screen to another end of the screen just to click Settings, Power and Shut Down feels like running a mile.

I know I can scroll through the charms by moving up and down right after the swipe from right, but that's not good enough. After selecting Settings, for example, I still have to move my mouse pointer to click Power.

Is there a way to do this? I can imagine it being very useful to many other users too.